# How can I put a floating image on the upper right corner of the page/top of 2nd column using multicol?

Tags: graphics, formatting, multicol, frame

I am trying to replicate the look of the 2nd edition AD&D Monstrous Manual. What I specifically want is to have an image defined at the start of the page, which is always in the top of the second column. This is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\let\chaptername\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{}
\newfontfamily{\league}{LeagueGothic}[
Path=./fonts/,
Extension = .ttf, 
UprightFont = *-Regular
]
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[noindentafter]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\LARGE\bfseries}{\thesection}{0em}{} 
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{0em}{} 
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{0em}{} 

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}
\titlespacing{\section}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0cm}{.5cm}{0cm}

\newcommand{\imagewidth}{0.95\linewidth}
\newcommand{\image}[1]{\fbox{\parbox{0.95\linewidth}{{\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{#1}\\}}}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[super]{nth}

\usepackage{multicol}
\raggedcolumns   

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}

\makeatletter
  \def\vhrulefill#1{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\@height#1\hfill \kern\z@}
\makeatother


\graphicspath{ {./img/} }


\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\def \booktitle {Multiversal Bestiary}
% \def \booksubtitle {A collection of deities for the world's most popular roleplaying games.}
\def \fulltitle {\booktitle}%: \booksubtitle}
\def \pubyear {2023}
\def \publisher {PUBLISHER NAME}
\def \authors {Simeon Armenchev \& Stoyan Stoyanov}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}[1][\contentsname]{%
  \section*{#1}
  \begin{multicols*}{2}
    \@starttoc{toc}
  \end{multicols*}
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\expandafter\def\expandafter\@afterheading\expandafter{\@afterheading\mbox{}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\remaining}
\newcommand{\underover}[1]{%
\setlength{\remaining}{\linewidth-\widthof{\textsc{#1}}}
\noindent$\overline{\underline{\textsc{#1}\hspace*{\remaining}}}$}

\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
  {\endminipage\par\medskip}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

  \begin{titlepage}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(char.base)]
      \node(char)[draw,fill=white,
        shape=circle,
        minimum width=3cm]
        {\Huge \bf PF1e};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  
  \null\vfill

  \begin{center}

  \hrulefill
  
  {\league{\fontsize{60}{60} \textbf{\booktitle}}}
  
  \hrulefill
  
  \vskip 1cm
  % {\Large \textbf{\textit{\booksubtitle}}}
  \vskip 2cm

  %\includegraphics[width=10cm]{rawpixel6261871}
  \vfill
  \vfill
  \textit{\authors}\\
  \small\today\\
  \end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\begin{center}
{\Huge \textbf{\textit{Credits}}}
\end{center}
\begin{tabular}{ l l }
 \textbf{Authors} & \authors \\ 
 \textbf{Editor} & Simeon Armenchev \\  
 \textbf{Designers} & \authors \\  
 \textbf{Layout} & Simeon Armenchev \\  
 \textbf{Artists} &   
\end{tabular}
\vskip 2cm


\noindent Copyright © \pubyear by \publisher \\
All rights reserved. This book or any portion thereof
may not be reproduced or used in any manner whatsoever
without the express written permission of the publisher, except as stated in the OGL License except for the use of brief quotations in a book review.

\newpage

\tableofcontents



\chapter{Behir \hfill  CR 8}
\vskip 0.0cm
\vhrulefill{0.1cm}
\vskip 0.3cm
{\color{blue}\vhrulefill{0.2cm}}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\textbf{XP} 6,400

N Huge magical beast

\textbf{Init} +1; \textbf{Senses} darkvision 60 ft., low-light vision; Perception +8


\subsubsection*{\color{blue}\underover{\textbf{DEFENSE}}}
\textbf{AC} 21, touch 9, flat-footed 20 (+1 Dex, +12 natural, –2 size)

\textbf{hp} 105 (10d10+50)

\textbf{Fort} +12, \textbf{Ref} +8, \textbf{Will} +5

\textbf{Immune} electricity 


\subsubsection*{\color{blue}\underover{\textbf{OFFENSE}}}
\textbf{Speed} 40 ft., climb 20 ft.

\textbf{Melee} bite +15 (2d6+9 plus grab)

\textbf{Space} 15 ft.; Reach 10 ft.

\textbf{Special Attacks} breath weapon (20-foot line, 7d6 electricity damage, Reflex DC 20 for half, usable every 1d4 rounds), constrict (2d6+9), rake (6 claws +14, 1d4+6), swallow whole (2d8+9 bludgeoning damage, AC 16, 10 hp)


\subsubsection*{\color{blue}\underover{\textbf{STATISTICS}}}
\textbf{Str} 23, \textbf{Dex} 12, \textbf{Con} 21, \textbf{Int} 7, \textbf{Wis} 14, \textbf{Cha} 12

\textbf{Base Atk} +10; \textbf{CMB} +18 (+22 grapple); \textbf{CMD} 29 (can’t be tripped)

\textbf{Feats} Alertness, Cleave, Great Cleave, Power Attack, Weapon Focus (bite)

\textbf{Skills} Climb +14, Perception +8, Stealth +5

\textbf{Languages} Common

\subsubsection*{\color{blue}\underover{\textbf{SPECIAL ABILITIES}}}
\subsection*{Grab (Ex)}

A behir’s grab attack works against creatures of any size category. It can constrict the same round it establishes a hold. On any round thereafter that it maintains its hold, the behir can choose to rake the grappled target or swallow it whole.

\begin{figure}[H]
\image{behir}
\end{figure}

\subsubsection*{\-\underover{\textbf{ECOLOGY}}}
\textbf{Environment} warm hills and deserts

\textbf{Organization} solitary or pair

\textbf{Treasure} double

{\setlength\parindent{20pt}\noindent
Temperamental and avaricious, the behir spends most of its time slithering through the sandy hills and desert cliffs that make up its territory, preying upon all creatures who dare to enter its hunting grounds. The creature’s six pairs of powerful, clawed legs remain folded against its sides most of the time, only extending in combat to grapple foes or carry the behir forward in a terrifying, low-slung gallop, or else when climbing the sheer cliff faces common to behir lairs.

The average behir is 40 feet long and weighs 4,000 pounds. In addition to the two prominent horns on its head, many have additional decorative spines at regular intervals along the central ridges of their backs.

While territorial and bestial in its fury, the behir is neither stupid nor necessarily evil, though its self-centeredness and tendency to lay claim to everything visible from its high lairs frequently bring it into conflict with other races. As such, a behir can often be bought off or reasoned with by those brave negotiators willing to get close enough to make their pitch. In these cases, a behir’s tendency to attack first and ask questions later (or not at all) means that anyone seeking to strike a deal must bring powerful incentives and impress the behir immediately with his offer.

It’s often been speculated that behirs are somehow related to blue dragons, but the exact nature of this link remains unknown. Most dragons deny any such association and look down on the behir for its relative lack of intelligence—a snubbing that infuriates the already short-tempered behir. Thanks to this casual disparagement, many behirs carry deep grudges against dragons, and attack without pause any who cross into their territories.}


\end{multicols*}

\include{OGL.tex}

\end{document}
```

And this is what I've currently got:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you use a float, if you want a fixed position?

Comment: @DG' Because I it's a multicol, which is dynamic. I need it in a fixed position, but I also need the text to be displaced, and for it to work in a multicol. Also I honestly have no idea what I'm doing half the time.